# Android Pepper Application: E/qi.path.sdklayout: Cannot create directory – Permission denied

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-permissions, pepper

Since quite a while, I've been trying to run an Android app for the humanoid robot Pepper on Mac OS 10.13.6. In the past, there occurred many issues when I was trying to run a virtual device in combination with the Pepper Emulator. When I tried to run the emulator with Android SDK version 30 or 29, I was always receiving an error message that there were "NO_CERTIFICATES" to permit the installation of the app. After trying the option to generate a signed bundle in Android Studio, no change was happening.

After downgrading to Android SDK version 23, it was finally possible to run the robot viewer while installing and starting the app on the virtual tablet device without any crash occurring. However the app didn't crash at this point, the following error message appeared in the log histroy:

E/qi.path.sdklayout: Cannot create directory '"/mnt/sdcard/.config/qimessaging"' error was: boost::filesystem::create_directories: Permission denied: "/mnt/sdcard/.config"
E/qi.os: Unable to create file: ''

As soon as I call the robot to execute an animation by clicking a button on the tablet interface, the app crashes and the following lines are printed to the log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLszd.png)

I thought that this error might be implied by the first error message. Therefore I tried to update the AndroidManifest.xml with this permission tag:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN0me.png)

Unfortunately, this did not change anything. So I hope to receive some help from your community. Also I would be extremly happy to receive some advice from you, @dfinn. I've read that you got around several issues to run a Pepper application on your Mac, is this correct?

Thanks a lot for all your support!

Answer (score 0):

The error `E/qi.path.sdklayout: Cannot create directory – Permission denied` has no visible consequence.
The real issue you have here is the one described in the backtrace, `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick`.
It looks like something is wrong with an `onClick` callback in your Android code.